# Sum in a Cross Table

Tags: r

I am new in R. Apologies if the questions is too silly.

I have a sample input data table as follows.

```
Column-1 Column-2 Column-3 
 FF       FF       2
 NN       NN       5
 FF       FF       2
 NN       NN       1
 FN       FF       3
```

Output should be

```
       FF   FN  NF  NN
    FF  4   0   0   0
    FN  3   0   0   0
    NF  0   0   0   0
    NN  0   0   0   6
```

I have used table() function, but it only gives "count", and not "sum". Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the little known `xtabs` function. Your data:

```
l <- c("FF", "FN", "NF", "NN")

data <- data.frame(
   Column1 = factor(c("FF", "NN", "FF", "NN", "FN"), levels = l),
   Column2 = factor(c("FF", "NN", "FF", "NN", "FF"), levels = l),
   Column3 = c(2, 5, 2, 1, 3))
```

---

```
xtabs(Column3 ~ ., data)
#        Column2
# Column1 FF FN NF NN
#      FF  4  0  0  0
#      FN  3  0  0  0
#      NF  0  0  0  0
#      NN  0  0  0  6
```

The output is a `table` but you can wrap it into `as.matrix` to get a `matrix`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `daply` function from `plyr` :

```
R> daply(mydf, .(Column.1, Column.2), summarize, sum(Column.3))
        Column.2
Column.1 FF   NN  
      FF 4    NULL
      FN 3    NULL
      NN NULL 6
```

And here is a solution with base R :

```
res <- with(mydf,
     by(Column.3, list(Column.1, Column.2), FUN=sum))
res <- as.table(res)
res[is.na(res)] <- 0
```

Which gives :

```
   FF NN
FF  4  0
FN  3  0
NN  0  6
```

Comment: Thank you both for prompt responses. Works great!

Answer (score 0):

For the future reader, you can use `tapply()` function like this way

`tapply(data$Column3, list(data$Column2, data$Column1), sum)`